# timerjob to make custom service application automated

Tags: service-application

I was trying to make use of the custom service appliaction which I got from the source,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193964.aspx, to make it automated by associating with a timer job. When I'm running the application, the timer job is not hitting.  When I try to debug the code it is not hitting at all.  Please help me out with this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using CriticalPath.SharePoint.Samples.WingtipCalculator;


namespace SampleTimerJob
{

   public class SampleJobDefinition : SPJobDefinition
    {
       public const string JobName = "SimpleJobDefinition"; 

        public SampleJobDefinition() : base() { }

        public SampleJobDefinition(SPService svcApp) :
            base(JobName, svcApp, null, SPJobLockType.Job) 
        {
            Title = "Simple Job Definition";
        }

        public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
        {
          //SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;

            SPSite mySite = new SPSite("http://ussecavdspdwk09/tax");
            SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb();

            SPServiceContext mySiteContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(mySite);
           // SPServiceContext mySiteContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(mySite);
                CalcServiceClient client = new CalcServiceClient(mySiteContext);
                client.AddTask(mySite.Url);


        }

    }




}
```

Comment: I can't answer your question as I don't work with timer jobs that often, but you do need to dispose of your myWeb and mySite objects.  The recommended approach is to open them in a using {} block so that they are disposed automatically

Comment: What version of SharePoint and what version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

shot in the dark - 1) Does your timer job have a defined schedule? and 2) are you restarting the Timer Service after deploying updates to your code?

[This post](http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/creatingcustomsharepointtimerjob2010/) might help a bit more with the Timer Job itself

Answer (score 0):

my guess:

you are attaching your debugger to the w3wp process (explicitely via debug -> attach to process for sp2007/sp2010, or by hitting f5 for vs2010/sp2010).

that is not the right process. Try attaching it to the owstimer, that is the process that the job runs in. press debug -> attach to process -> owstimer